# Insert current datetime into oracle db using stored procedure

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I need to insert current datetime into oracle database via a storedprocedure call. I tried #[server.dateTime]. Also tried #[function:date] but both are failing with below error

`Message               : Invalid conversion requested (java.sql.SQLException).
SQL Code              : 17132
Payload Type          : org.mule.util.CaseInsensitiveHashMap
SQL State             : 99999`

Below is my config. Thanks for any help.

```
<batch:step name="UpdateDatabase">
<db:stored-procedure config-ref="Oracle_Configuration"  doc:name="UpdateDatabase">
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{call
 tokens.UpdateData(:P_ID,:P_TOKEN,:P_CC,:P_DATE_UPDATED,:P_UPDATED_BY,:P_RESULT)}]]></db:parameterized-query>
<db:in-param name="P_ID" type="INTEGER" value="123456"/>
<db:in-param name="P_TOKEN" type="VARCHAR" value="test_token"/>
<db:in-param name="P_CC" type="VARCHAR" value="test_cc"/>
<db:in-param name="P_DATE_UPDATED" type="DATE" value="#
[server.dateTime]"/>
<db:in-param name="P_UPDATED_BY" type="VARCHAR" value="migrator"/>
<db:out-param name="P_RESULT" type="NUMERIC"/>
</db:stored-procedure>
</batch:step>
```

Comment: Try with `#[function:now]`

Comment: Thanks it worked. Also how can i pass a custom date?

Comment: What do you mean by custom date? Formatting?

Comment: If i want to insert date e.g 01/05/2017 15:00:00

Comment: You can do formatting along with function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MEL expressions instead of function:

`#[server.dateTime.format('dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss')]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression:`#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss]`

Answer (score 0):

use #[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss]